# Trigger Event when listView Item is selected programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, event-handling

I wrote an application with listViews which fill other listViews on click event. Means that when the Row in the first listView is selected it fills the second listView with the related list like dynamic dropdown lists. I am googling for hours now but I cannot find a solution.
This is what I tried but nothing will trigger the `listView1_SelectedIndexChanged` Event.

Thanks for your help it is very appreciated.

I tried this after researching:

```
    listView1.Focus();
    listView1.Items[index is variable].Selected = true;
    listView1.Click += new EventHandler(listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

It actually selects the row in the listView and also the row gets highlighted blue but the event is still not triggered.

Comment: You should move `listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged;` to form Load event handler or put it in constructor after InitializeComponent, then define `private void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){ /* code */}`.

Comment: Hi Reza thanks for your message. The private void for `listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` is already defined but it is not triggered from the code. When I put a `listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged` in the Load event handler like you mentioned first I get an error with this line of code in it.

Comment: Subscribe the event in one place (like constructor after initialize component), or in load, or using designer (not all, only one of the places). Then triggering the event happens when you set an item Selected = true.

Comment: Hi Reza, sorry I am new to C# and Visual Studio so I do not fully understand what you are saying. I tried to put it directly after initialize component but it still only selects the row (Multi-Select is on) but it does not trigger.